# New user don't save into MongoDB after checking unique email and username

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm new to web-development field. I wanted to create a "user registration & login" app. But I'm failed to save unique user info into MongoDB at registration point. Here is my code...

**Model:**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    // User Schema
    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
       name: { type: String, required: true },
       email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
       username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
       password: { type: String, required: true }
    } );
    const User = module.exports = mongoose.model( 'User', UserSchema );
```

**Controller:**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const passport = require('passport');
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const Users = require('../models/userModel');

    // post route for Register Process
    router.post( '/register', ( req, res ) => {
       const name = req.body.name;
       const email = req.body.email;
       const username = req.body.username;
       const password = req.body.password;
       const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;

       // Check email or username already exists in DB
       Users.find( { $or: [ {email: email}, {username: username} ] }, ( err, users ) => {
          if( err ){ return console.log( err ); }
          else{
             // If email or username already exists in DB
             if( users ){
                if( users.length > 0 ){
                   for( let i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ){
                      let hasEmail = ( users[i].email == email );
                      let hasUsername = ( users[i].username == username );
                      if( hasEmail ){
                         return console.log( 'Email already registered.' );
                      }
                      else if( hasUsername ){
                         return console.log( 'Username already taken.' );
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
             else{

                // If email or username is unique / not exists in DB
                // then save / create a new user
                let newUser = new Users( {
                   name: name,
                   email: email,
                   username: username,
                   password: password,
                   confirmPassword: confirmPassword
                } );

                // Password hashing
                bcrypt.genSalt( 10, ( err, salt ) => {
                   bcrypt.hash( newUser.password, salt, ( err, hash ) => {
                      if( err ){ return console.log( err ); }
                      newUser.password = hash;

                      // New user save in DB / create a new user
                      newUser.save( ( err ) => {
                         if( err ){
                            return console.log( err );
                         } else{
                            return console.log( 'You have registered successfully' );
                         }
                      } );
                   } );
                } );
             }
          }
       } );
    } );
    module.exports = router;
```

All code (with server) are OK. If input `email` or `username` anyone already exists in DB then got an `error` message. But if value is unique, the `newUser.save()` don't trigger (don't save into DB) and not any `error` message shown in console or browser, Page continuous loading. Here I used `$or: [ {email: email}, {username: username} ]` to find existing user by `email` or `username`.

**How can I fixed this issue? Please, help me out.**

Comment: `But if value is unique` means you are giving new username or email which DB don't have, in that situation its not saving into DB?? Also can you print `users` if you give new username or email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because of this line `if( users ) {}`. Even if you do give unique email and password `users` will be an empty array. In which case:

```
if (users) {
   console.log('Have users'); <- This will get executed although email and username is unique
}
```

Instead you can do it like this:

```
if (users && users.length > 0) {
   console.log('Have users');
}
```

**Also, your schema doesn't have `confirmPassword` field in it.**

**Suggestion:** You are nesting your code too much. You can simplify your code like this.

```
if( err ) {
  console.log( err );
  return;
}
// else is not needed
if( users && users.length > 0 ){
  // DO YOUR STUFF

  return;
}
// else is not needed again
let newUser = new Users( { ... } );
```

Comment: Many many thanks for your effort. You saved my time.
`confirmPassword` field don't show error. I'll fix it.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When there are no matches find() returns `[]`, so modify your code as follows:

Remove `if( users ){` and check for length directly

```
 if( users.length > 0 ){
//do stuff for existing user
 } else {
      let newUser = new Users( {
       name: name,
       email: email,
       username: username,
       password: password,
       confirmPassword: confirmPassword
     } );

//save function
}
```

IN your case always your `if( users)` will be satisfied and it won't execute `else` part which will trigger `save`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved it using above answer and I think your solution maybe work too...

Comment: Removing the check for users prior to checking users.length, will throw an error if users is empty.